# Two Grammatical questions over sentences extracted from The Economist

Tags: formal-language, compounds

> The capture of the drone took place on the outer perimeter of China’s expansive claim to the sea, about 50 miles (80km) from the Philippine port of Subic Bay, which was once home to a large American naval base (see map). **It appeared calculated** to show China’s naval reach, with only minimal risk of any conflict—the American ship that was operating the drone, the Bowditch, **is a not a combat vessel.**

The above paragraph is extracted from [Warning shot](http://www.economist.com/news/china/21712159-tough-times-loom-america-south-china-sea-china-seizes-underwater-drone-and-sends)

Does the first sentence in bold means that 'it appeared that it was calculated to...'?
If it is, what is the *it* referring to?
If not, how should I put it?

The second sentence, is it grammatically correct?

Comment: As a side note, the article opens with the word **it** ("It was an operation..."), a narrative use that means, roughly, *the-situation-I-am-about-to-tell-you-about*.  Compare *It was the best of times, it was the worst of times...*

Comment: Thank you @TRomano! I think someone keeps deleting my comments, so this one probably would also be deleted. Hope it will last till you see it.

Comment: Don't be bothered by those deletions. **it** is just someone's compulsion. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **It appeared calculated** to show China's naval reach . . .

*It appeared calculated* can be interpreted in two ways. You can interpret "calculated" as an adjective, meaning "it appeared to be planned and intended", which would follow the pattern "subject+appear+adjective". It's normally interchangeable with "it appeared as adjective".

The interpretation which applied here, though, was interpretation of "calculated" as a participle. "It appeared to be a calculation of China's naval reach . . . " In other words, you're right.

> . . . **is *a* not *a* combat vessel**.
>   <sub>italic emphasis mine</sub>

Now this is more interesting. It reminds me of constructions like "an NARQ", which is a term previously used while moderating Stack Overflow questions. It stood for "a Not A Real Question".

[Articles in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_articles#Usage) normally tend to appear as the first element in a [noun phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase), before the nominal. There's the possibility of articles appearing in other places, of course. It usually occurs in colloquial language when using simpler but more words is preferable to using fewer but formal words people are less likely to understand.

Therefore, you normally see constructions such as "a getting-to-know-you meeting" instead of "a familiarization meeting" or anything that fancy. There are also more extreme cases where the hyphens are eventually removed and it's officially become a word, such as "whack**a**mole". As you see, articles can very well appear in the middle of such words. We call those words [compounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_(linguistics)#Noun.E2.80.93noun_compounds).

Colloquial speech, and sometimes formal speech (but not academic) is usually not restrained to what compounds it can use. The most important thing here is not having to explain what you just said.

So, in a bizarre context where "not a combat vessel" is a compound, most likely the 'collapsed' version of an acronym in a technical military context, it would be acceptable to say "a not a combat vessel", and the author would have "an NACV" in mind.

That's most likely not the case though, and this was just a typo that escaped the proofreaders (I had to read it thrice to notice it too).

Comment: That 'a' is certainly just a typo, and I think your speculative discursion on the issue will confuse many readers.

Comment: Tony I think I do explicitly mention that the context is unlikely and this was a typo.

Comment: Impossible, not just unlikely.

Comment: Why impossible? Are you implying that 'a not a real question' is ungrammatical? Please explain

Comment: Certainly 'a not a real question' is ungrammatical.

Comment: Well, then let's just agree to disagree. Because when a number of native speakers of English reasonably use something, it becomes grammatical.

Comment: Playing by your rules, everything is grammatical, which renders the concept meaningless.

Comment: No, what I said is actually the basis of [the descriptive approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_description). I refrained from the unnecessary details.  Note that I said 'number', not 'one'. A native speaker claiming 'asdfgasdfyd8h' doesn't make it an acceptable utterance obviously. :) BTW, should we move to chat? The comment thread is getting long.

Comment: -1 How is the big issue the discussion of the extra "a" and not the fact that the poster claims "It appeared to be calculated.." means it "It appeared to be calculating China's naval reach..." Which is certainly not the correct interpretation. 

"It appeared to be calculated to show China's reach" means the Chinese wanted to let the USA know they can police/defend the waters they are laying claim to without risking the possibility of a military skirmish by choosing to engage with a non combat craft.

Comment: @DRF Oh, right. I'm a bit stumped on how to find an alternative phrasing that is as short and still makes sense. Open to suggestions.

Comment: If you would like to extend this discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54440/discussion-on-answer-by-m-a-r-two-grammatical-questions-over-sentences-extracte) for your convenience.

Comment: When I saw that sentence in the article, I was thinking maybe it's like what you said in your answer, it could be a compound, so I did google the supposedly compound, but didn't get much results therefore I post the question, and you pointed that out! I like your answer. It helps me understanding all the possibilities. It's very clear. Thank you MAR.

Comment: Actually you pointed all the parts I was confusing about. The adjective and compound part.

Comment: Glad I could be of help @Jas :)

Answer (score 13):

Your interpretation is correct. "It" refers to the capture of the drone under the described conditions.

I had completely missed the extra "a" hiding in plain sight.  Yeah, that's a typo.  It should read "...is not a combat vessel".